# babel 7 not transpiling when used in rollup with typescript plugin

Tags: typescript, babeljs, rollup

I Cannot seem to get rollup-plugin-babel to work in my typescript project.
The .ts code compiles and rollup packages, map files are generated but babel does not transpile it.

Also if I run `npx babel lab.js --out-file lab-es5.js` babel seem to work just fine.

This my rollup.config.js

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import sourcemaps from 'rollup-plugin-sourcemaps';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

var plugins = [
    nodeResolve({
        module: true,
        jsnext: true,
        main: true,
        preferBuiltins: false
    }),
    commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/**',  // Default: undefined
        ignoreGlobal: false,  // Default: false
    }),
    typescript(/*{ plugin options }*/),
    babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        runtimeHelpers: true
    }),
    sourcemaps()
];

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/lab.ts',
        plugins,
        output: {
            name: "TablePager",
            file: 'lab.js',
            format: 'iife',
            sourcemap: true
        }
    }
];
```

and this is my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

If you have any clues as to what I am doing wrong I am greatful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanations

By default, `@rollup/plugin-babel` have the following extensions enabled:

```
.js
.jsx
.es6
.es
.mjs
```

And so, there are two things important to set when using `@rollup/plugin-babel` along with `@rollup/plugin-typescript`.

1. You have to tell it to use the TypeScript extension (which is not enabled by default).
2. You have to tell it which files you want to transpile.

For some reasons, the documentation says that by default, all files are transpiled. Which is not the case for files having the TypeScript extension. So you have to set the `include` option manually.

Fortunately for the second option, you can tell it to use a glob pattern. Setting a folder won't work.

### Example

Here is an example. In this context, all TypeScript files to transpile are in the `src` folder.

```js
"use strict";

import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";

import { resolve } from "path";

export default {
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        babel({
            extensions: [".ts"],
            include: resolve("src", "**", "*.ts")
        })
    ];
};
```

### Links

- [Rollup documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/).
- [Babel plugin for Rollup documentation](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel).
- [TypeScript plugin for Rollup documentation](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/typescript).

Comment: This answer solved my problem, specifically, in my case, `include: resolve("src", "**", "*.ts"),` was missing from Rollup config which led to `Set`s not being transpiled from TS files (empty arrays yielded) which luckily threw Vue.js on the front-end which was feeding from UMD build. That's how I spotted it. Unit tests on ES builds all passed before and after the fix... Very sneaky bug category. Thank you Amin!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Microsoft's [TypeScript-Babel-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter#using-rollup) and the rollup section.

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import pkg from './package.json';

const extensions = [
  '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx',
];

const name = 'RollupTypeScriptBabel';

export default {
  input: './src/index.ts',

  // Specify here external modules which you don't want to include in your bundle (for instance: 'lodash', 'moment' etc.)
  // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#external-e-external
  external: [],

  plugins: [
    // Allows node_modules resolution
    resolve({ extensions }),

    // Allow bundling cjs modules. Rollup doesn't understand cjs
    commonjs(),

    // Compile TypeScript/JavaScript files
    babel({ extensions, include: ['src/**/*'] }),
  ],

  output: [{
    file: pkg.main,
    format: 'cjs',
  }, {
    file: pkg.module,
    format: 'es',
  }, {
    file: pkg.browser,
    format: 'iife',
    name,

    // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#output-globals-g-globals
    globals: {},
  }],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.babelrc` is missing `@babel/preset-typescript`. Try installing the package and adding it to the configuration:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

Comment: But I am not using babel to transpile ts only to go from es6 to es5. So the preset-typescript shouldn't be needed. Am I correct?

Comment: @JGoodgive Ah sorry, I misread. Did you try setting the `extensions` option of `rollup-plugin-babel` so that it includes `.ts` files? Like `babel({ extensions: ['.ts', '.js'], runtimeHelpers: true })`.