# Babel does not compile when using Rollup's TypeScript plugin with Babel

Tags: typescript, rollup

I can't get @rollup/plugin-typescript to work with @rollup/plugin-babel, and the JS generated from TS code is not translated by Babel

I looked for solutions to related problems, but they didn't seem to work([babel 7 not transpiling when used in rollup with typescript plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437261/babel-7-not-transpiling-when-used-in-rollup-with-typescript-plugin))

Below is my rollup config

```
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import pluginTypescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import pluginCommonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import pluginNodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";

import { babel } from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import * as path from "path";
import pkg from "./package.json";

const moduleName = pkg.name.replace(/^@.*\//, "");
const inputFileName = "src/main.ts";
const author = pkg.author;
const banner = `
  /**
   * @license
   * author: ${author}
   * ${moduleName}.js v${pkg.version}
   * Released under the ${pkg.license} license.
   */
`;

export default [
  {
    input: inputFileName,
    output: [
      {
        name: moduleName,
        file: pkg.browser,
        format: "iife",
        //sourcemap: "inline",
        banner,
      },
      {
        name: moduleName,
        file: pkg.browser.replace(".js", ".min.js"),
        format: "iife",
        sourcemap: "inline",
        banner,
        plugins: [terser()],
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      pluginTypescript(),
      pluginCommonjs({
        extensions: [".js", ".ts"],
      }),
      babel({
        extensions: [".ts"],
        include: path.resolve("src", "**", "*.ts"),
        babelHelpers: "bundled",
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, ".babelrc.js"),
      }),
      pluginNodeResolve({
        browser: true,
      }),// 
    ],
  }
];
```

Here is my Babel configuration

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 1%, last 2 versions, ie > 11"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "absoluteRuntime": false,
        "corejs": 3,
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true,
        "version": "^7.13.17"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Rollup and related versions that I use

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/helpers": "^7.13.17",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^18.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "rollup": "^2.45.2",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.5",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amipei/cookie": "0.0.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.17",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.13.17",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Where did I go wrong? Please answer me. Rollup has been torturing me for days

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this preset - npm install it you don't have it

```
 "presets": [ '@babel/preset-typescript' ]
```